# ios google map custom marker

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers

Hi i am using google map in that i want use marker like below image
[image: marker i want]

i have done code

```
UIView *markerview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 102)];
markerview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glow-marker2.png"]];
UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 47, 70)];
imgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgview.image = img;
imgview.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
imgview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[markerview addSubview:imgview];
marker.icon = [self imageWithView:markerview];
marker.map = mapview;
```

it is giving me output

[image: getting output]

can anyone tell me why this black background is coming? how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue with you are setting Image as a background of Your view.

```
markerview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glow-marker2.png"]];
```

I suggest to make that view Background as a clear color and set `opaque=NO` and set image in to imageview and add this image as a **subview** of your `markerview`

Hope you issue going to be solve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you make your UIView to Image. try below code

```
    - (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```